# Logstash creating directory too early

Tags: linux, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, oracle-enterprise-linux

I have my logstash instance create a new directory everyday to store its logs. The config file is below. It seems to create a directory (and start using it) in the evening a day early; as opposed to creating it right after midnight (when the date actually changes). I am on the West coast (UTC−08:00). I am on an OEL os.

Configuration:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 6379
  }
}

filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime('-08:00')"
    }
}

output {
  file {
    path => ["/logstash-1.4.1/logs/%{+YYYY-MM-dd}/logstash_in.txt"]
  }
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => http
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

My system date and time are correct:

```
[root@xxx]# date
Mon Jul 14 18:22:37 PDT 2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short answer, the file output path timestamp `%{+YYYY-MM-dd}` is refer to UTC time. 
That's means your directory will be create at your evening time.

For long answer, you can refer to the [file output source code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb#L63). The path is

```
path = event.sprintf(@path)
```

And drill down to the `event.rb`

```
t = @data["@timestamp"]
formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(key[1 .. -1])\
  .withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone::UTC)
#next org.joda.time.Instant.new(t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000).toDateTime.toString(formatter)
# Invoke a specific Instant constructor to avoid this warning in JRuby
#  > ambiguous Java methods found, using org.joda.time.Instant(long)
org.joda.time.Instant.java_class.constructor(Java::long).new_instance(
  t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000
).to_java.toDateTime.toString(formatter)
```

The path paramter `%{+YYYY-MM-dd}` is based on the UTC time: `(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone::UTC)`.

So, there are two solution to do what you need,

a) Modify event.rb to use your timezone, instead of UTC.

b) Create a your own day field and use that field you specific `%{+YYYY-MM-dd}`
Here is my configuration:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            ownTime = event['@timestamp'].localtime('-08:00')
            event['day'] = ownTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        "
    }
}

output {
    file {
            path => "/logstash-1.4.1/logs/%{day}/logstash_in.txt"
    }
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the timezone based on the timezone's name:

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "@timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
    timezone => "America/New_York"
  }
}
```